# c++ decrement and increment operator

Tags: c

I am newbie to coding and am confused about increment and decrement operators.

```
int a = 10;
int b = ++a + ++a + ++a;
```

According to youtube videos it should print 39 but it prints 37.
Can someone explain me the reason ?

Comment: Those youtube videos aren't very good, then.

Comment: This should not be closed...

Comment: I feel an urge to find these videos and tell the author everything I think of him...

Comment: @snb Why is that?

Comment: I looked at that post but cant find anything useful :(

Comment: Even the fourth answer?

Comment: I understood that but if i make 4 ++a it gives 51 so in that case compiler makes numbers 12 12 13 14. Why first ++a is not 11 ? I didn`t understand that.

Comment: @R.Bayram Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: @R.Bayram: C doesn't force left-to-right evaluation (except in a few cases that don't apply here), and it doesn't require that the side effect of `++` be applied immediately after evaluation.  Because of this, the result of an expression like `++a + ++a + ++a` is not guaranteed to have a consistent result across different implementations, programs, or even different runs of the same program.  The behavior is *undefined*, meaning it shouldn't have *any* specific result - it's a coding error, but the compiler isn't required to complain about it.

Comment: What baffles me is why anyone would care about the result of such ghastly code.  It only ever appears in SO questions, (thousands of them), and is of negative use to future users/visitors:(

Comment: @EugeneSh. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvcXju_jNWQ here be the one I presume. I've left a comment, it requires upvotes to appear at top. 60k views; and we got 2 questions from it within an hour today.

Comment: @melpomene ^ ;)